# Return most recent NSManagedObjects only from NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController and need to return distinct objects based on their latest dates and name. Each date is stored as an NSDate.

**Example:**

Object1
name:Object1
date:01/01/2001

Object2
name:Object
date:01/02/2001

Object3
name:OtherObject
date:01/10/2001

Object4
name:OtherObject
date:02/01/2001

**Expected results (Return only the latest date objects when a duplicate is found):**

name:Object
date:01/02/2001

name:OtherObject
date:02/01/2001

// Below returns everything sorted correctly although I only need the latest of each match based on the date.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Create the sort descriptors array.
NSSortDescriptor *name = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *date = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:name, date, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

***EDIT***
As of now I am fetching all of the objects into an array, for each object in array1 I cycle thru and add / compare it to the latest matching objects in array2 with the same name and remove the oldest date entry from array2 then I'm left with unique latest dates in array2. I was hoping there was a less cumbersome way to do this with a single fetchrequest / subquery.

Comment: I am able to return sorted objects based on name and date and now I would like only the latest of each duplicate to be displayed. Having a brain fart today on this one...

Comment: Use the fetch request's `fetchLimit` property.

Comment: How would the fetchLimit property help when returning multiple different objects? That would result in only 1 object total if set to 1.

Comment: You said you want the latest object? Or wait, dedupe the results by keeping the latest and removing the others?

Comment: Latest object(s). Basically removing duplicates based on their date field. I need all objects to return unless a dupe is found, then return only the latest of that object based on date.

Comment: Can two objects share the same `date` yet be distinct?

Comment: Two objects of the same name will never share the same date in this case... Therefore, I only want to display the latest object(s) when duplicates are found.

Comment: Uh… finding it a little difficult to get my head around. Is this correct? http://pastebin.com/PNCE1jX7

Answer (score 0):

Core Data doesn't automatically track insertion order. When you get an fetched object back, its entities will be in any random order.

My immediate thoughts on this are that you need another attribute to track the insertion time and reorder/sort by this attribute.

So, your attribute would be need to be a date time with seconds. You would call this:

`NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];`

and store it in the attribute. When you fetch the object, sort by the key of this attribute.

Comment: I appreciate the response although sorting isn't exactly the issue. The current code snippet does sorting fine, I am trying to remove duplicates based on a timestamp that matches a name. I can easily do this with an array although doing this in a single fetch is killing me. A subquery seems to be the correct direction IMO. For instance, setting the offset to 1 on a subquery sorted by date would be perfect it seems. For now I am iterating the array and sending the newest object to a new array.

Comment: ah ok, perhaps I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Create an NSSet of the attribute `name` to return a unique set of data.
2. Fetch the latest attribute `date` for each attribute `name`.

For example:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Object"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *objects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest];

NSMutableArray *arrayObjectNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Object *object in objects) {
    [arrayObjectNames addObject:object.name];
}
NSSet *setObjectNames = [NSSet setWithArray:arrayObjectNames];

NSString *key = @"name";
NSMutableDictionary *dictNamesDates = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];     
for (NSString *objectName in setObjectNames) {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchName = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Object"]; 
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, objectName];
    [fetchName setPredicate:predicate];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    [fetchName setSortDescriptors:@[sortDate]];
    Object *targetObject = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchName] lastObject];
    if (targetObject) [dictNamesDates setObject:targetObject.date forKey:objectName];
    //OR as an alternative but achieving the same outcome...
    if (targetObject) [dictNamesDates setValue:targetObject.date forKey:targetObject.name];
}
```

This should create an `NSMutableDictionary` that contains each attribute `name` as the key and the corresponding latest attribute `date` as the value.

Does this help?

Comment: Although this more than likely would work I am hoping to achieve this in a single fetch using either a subquery or perhaps a predicate if possible. As of now I am fetching all of the objects into unique arrays based on their names then sorting by dates and adding all of the objects at index 0 to a new array. Although this works I would imagine there would be a less cumbersome way. Or I was at least hoping there would be. ;-) Thank you for the response.